# TikZ trapezium issues

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hy guys,
I need little help, please. I need to produce following trapezium using tikZ.

So far I have this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 1.5pt]
\node (a)
[shape=trapezium,
trapezium left angle=82,
trapezium right angle=41,
draw,
minimum height=2.1*1cm] {};


\node [below right] at (a.top left corner) {$\alpha$};
\node [below left] at (a.top right corner) {$\beta$}; 
\node [above right] at ([xshift=.1cm]a.bottom left corner) {82};
\node [above left] at ([xshift=-.4cm]a.bottom right corner) {42}; 
\node(v1) at (-1,1){};
\draw(v1) -- (-2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Can you please help me

Comment: among others, have a look at TikZ "angle" `pic`... you have an example at the beginning of the PGF manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library for that. The `angles` library, it offers a built-in `pic` type appropriately called `angle`, if you define three coordinates `(A)` `(B)` and `(C)`, where `B` is the vertex, and issue `\pic{angle}` an angle line will be drawn between the `A--B` and `B--C` lines. Alternatively you can say `\pic{angle=C1--C2--C3}`, where `C`s are coordinates previously defined. If ou wish to also draw the // as in your example Picture, you can define a new `pic` type for that.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, angles, quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw angle/.style args={#1--#2--#3 with #4}{%
                        insert path={%
                            foreach \i/\j in {#1/A,#2/B,#3/C}{(\i) coordinate (\j)}%
                            pic[angle style, #4]{angle}}
                            },
                    angle style/.style={draw, thin},
                    bars/.pic={\draw (80:-0.5) -- (80:0.5) ++(0:.1) -- ++(80:-1);},
                    line width = 1.5pt]
\node[draw, 
      shape=trapezium,
      trapezium left angle=82,
      trapezium right angle=41,
      minimum height=2.1*1cm] (a) {};
\path (a.bottom left corner) coordinate (T1)
      (a.top left corner) coordinate (T2)
      (a.top right corner) coordinate (T3)
      (a.bottom right corner) coordinate (T4);
\draw[draw angle={T4--T1--T2 with {angle radius=2.4em, "$82^\circ$"}},
      draw angle={T1--T2--T3 with "$\alpha$"},
      draw angle={T2--T3--T4 with "$\beta$"},
      draw angle={T3--T4--T1 with {angle radius=3.2em, angle eccentricity=0.7, "$41^\circ$"}}];
\draw ([shift={(.5*\pgflinewidth,.5*\pgflinewidth)}]T1) ++(-1,0) coordinate (tmp) -- pic[pos=.3,thin, scale=0.5]{bars}([shift={(.5*\pgflinewidth,.5*\pgflinewidth)}]T1);
\draw ([shift={(.5*\pgflinewidth,-.5*\pgflinewidth)}]tmp|-T2) -- pic[pos=.3,thin, scale=0.5]{bars} ([shift={(.5*\pgflinewidth,-.5*\pgflinewidth)}]T2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I'll try to finish what is left :) Have a nice day

Comment: You're welcome! But the preffered way of saying thank's here in TeX.SX is to **upvote** helpful posts and, when it's the case, **accept** correct answers. `:)` By the way, I think this is the first time I've been called "Sir" (I'm 25).  `;P`

Comment: I clicked like 5 times but vote casts by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicity... When I earn my 15, I'll be back :)

Comment: btw.There is a first time for everything :D